# Implement a range behaviour in Python using iterators

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, iterator, interval

I've been assigned the following Python homework:

> Implement myrange that acts like `range` using iterators. Define a function `myrange`and  define a class `MyRange`.

We've just seen iterators, so I think I'm asked to use them. I am not required to write a sophisticated code, but only something that allows the range-for loop syntax.

Professor said that, roughly, an iterator is an object for which the dunder method `__next__` is provided. I've seen there are similar questions here. However, none of them is defining the `__next__` method in a class.

---

So, here's what I did: first I implemented `MyRange` class and then `my range`. After that, I did two tests.

**Question:** It works, but I'd like to be sure from you if I solved correctly the question, I mean, if this is what I was supposed to do :-) As I said, I've just seen what is an iterator.

```
class MyRange():
    
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.check()
        self.index = -1
        
    def check(self):
        assert len(self.data)>0, "Not enough data"
            
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    
    def __next__(self):
        if self.index == len(self.data)-1:
            raise StopIteration
        self.index= self.index+1
        return self.data[self.index]

        




def my_range(*args):
    return MyRange((args))

print("Tests using MyRange class \n")

for i in MyRange((1,2,3,4)):
    print(i)    


print("Tests with range for loop \n")
for i in my_range(1,2,3,4,5,"Hello"):
    print(i)


r = MyRange((1,2,3,4,"Last Value"))
print(next(r))
print(next(r)) 
print(next(r))
print(next(r)) 
print(next(r)) 
print(next(r))
```

I'll show here the output, which seems the correct one:

```
1
2
3
4
Tests with range for loop 

1
2
3
4
5
Hello
1
2
3
4
Last Value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled3.py", line 45, in <module>
    print(next(r)) #<-- Raises StopIteration
  File "Untitled3.py", line 16, in __next__
    raise StopIteration
StopIteration
```

Comment: If `myrange()` is supposed to act like `range()`, shouldn't it take similar arguments: `start`, `stop`, and `step`? It doesn't seem like your implementation is following the instructions, but you obviously have more context than I do. A range is a device to generate integers (integers often used to index into a data collection), but you have implemented `myrange()` to take the data collection itself as an argument. Perhaps you can edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @FMc Unfortunately the text of the assignment was the short one I wrote at the beginning of my post. So far what we know is only that we need to use `__next__` in our class. I think I can fix this point. For the moment, assuming that the class `MyRange` is correct, do you think that `my_range` is implemented correctly?

Comment: The assignment seems to be asking to implement `range` two different ways (1) as a function (e.g. using `yield` in a loop), and (2) as a class (e.g. having `__iter__` and `__next__` methods).

Comment: No, based on my reading of the assignment, I think both `MyRange` and `my_range()` are incorrect. You have successfully implemented an iterable object (`MyRange`), but it is **not** an iterable object that behaves at all like `range()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You have an iterator

Your code implements an iterator, you are right. You have defined a `__next__` method and it works well.

I would tweak your code slightly, though:

- remove the `check` because iterators can be empty and that is okay;
- fix minor spacing issues around operators, etc;
- use augmented assignment to increment;
- change order of statements in `__next__` to be more idiomatic.

All in all, `MyRange` would end up looking like this:

```py
class MyRange():
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.index = -1
            
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    
    def __next__(self):
        self.index += 1
        if self.index == len(self.data):
            raise StopIteration
        return self.data[self.index]
```

In particular, the changes to `__next__` are because you start by setting `self.index` to the value of the index *you would like to read*. Then, just before reading the value from `data`, you ensure you can actually use that index and raise `StopIteration` if you can't.

## `range` is not any iterator

However, the "problem statement" says to implement an iterator *that behaves like `range`*, and as brought to your attention in the comments, `range` is a very specific iterator that can take up to 3 arguments: `start`, `stop`, and `step`.

Take a look at the docs for the range function [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).

Having said that, solving this "issue" does not need to be very difficult.
You could do something as simple as having `my_range` take the three arguments,
generate the `data` you need, and then feed it into `MyRange` to iterate, but that seems like a waste.

What *I think* is more or less the intended approach, is to define `MyRange` to expect the `start`, `stop`, and `step` values, and the `my_range` function is what the user calls, which then fills in the `start`, `stop`, and `step` values that are used by default and calls `MyRange`.

E.g.,

- `my_range(10)` would call `MyRange(0, 10, 1)`;
- `my_range(4, 12)` would call `MyRange(4, 12, 1)`;
- `my_range(0, 13, -3)` would call `MyRange(0, 13, -3)`.

(In the examples above, I assumed you changed `MyRange` to do what I described.)

Therefore, just for the sake of clarity: what would be happening is that the `__next__` method would use the three arguments `start`, `stop`, and `step` (and possibly other auxiliary variables you create) to *compute* the successive values, instead of generating all of them at once and then returning one by one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got the point! So the signature of `my_range` should be `my_range(start, stop,step)` too, right?

Comment: @bobinthebox yes, that is _my interpretation_ of the problem statement :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to fix this :-) @RGS

Comment: @bobinthebox good luck! But sorry, just to be clear, probably your `my_range` function also has to work with a single argument, `my_range(stop)` and two arguments, `my_range(start, stop)`, just like `range` does, yeah?

Comment: I agree, I should use default arguments to achieve this behaviour, right? @RGS

Comment: Yes @bobinthebox , default arguments are probably the way to go here. Just be careful with what values you choose as the default arguments ;)